# TypeORM Subscriber AfterInsert Can't Find Record

Tags: typeorm

I have a few Entities `Action`, and `GPKAsset`

In the `ActionSubscriber.ts` I would like to perform certain things based on the contract column as you can see below.

The problem I am encountering is on `await actionManager.addRelationAccount(action);` it is throwing exceptions saying that the record doesn't exist in actions. This is quite confusing because I have the id of the action and this is the `afterInsert` event.

I am guessing either I am doing something wrong or it's some sort of race condition, or it's a bug?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

#### Action.ts

```js
export class Action extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

REMOVED COLUMNS AND OTHER RELATIONSHIPS TO REDUCE CLUTTER

    @ManyToMany(() => GPKAsset, gpkAsset => gpkAsset.actions)
    gpkAssets: GPKAsset[];
```

#### GPKAsset.ts

```js
export class GPKAsset extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Index()
    @Column()
    contract: string;

REMOVED COLUMNS AND OTHER RELATIONSHIPS TO REDUCE CLUTTER

    @ManyToMany(() => Action, action => action.gpkAssets)
    @JoinTable({name:'gpkassets_actions'})
    actions: Action[];
```

#### ActionSubscriber.ts

```js
@EventSubscriber()
export class ActionSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Action> {
    listenTo() {
        return Action;
    }

    async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<Action>): Promise<Promise<any> | void> {

        let action: Action = event.entity;
        switch (event.entity.contract) {
            case 'simpleassets:createlog':
                let gpkAsset: GPKAsset | null = new GPKAsset();
                gpkAsset = await gpkassetManager.createGPKAssetFromAction(action);
                await actionManager.addRelationAccount(action);
                if (gpkAsset !== null) {
                     await actionManager.addRelationGPKAsset(action, gpkAsset))
                }
                break;
            case 'simpleassets:transfer':
                await gpkassetManager.transferGPKAssetOwnership(action);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. I enabled query logging and realized that typeorm is kind of batching the queries, both the original and the subscriber query inside the same transaction. That's why it's unable to find the record. I'm still figuring out how to solve this